# Why are Xcode breakpoints expanded automatically?

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

I'm facing with a Xcode problem.
I have some breakpoints, and when I run my project, all the breakpoints are **automatically expanded**.

See this pic:

[image: breakpoints expanded]

How can I tell Xcode to **NOT** expand them ?

Comment: What Xcode version do you use? I'm using 9.0.1 and I don't have the issue. Maybe this is related to objective-c as well, since I'm testing with Swift code right now.

Comment: I'm using Xcode 9.0..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have selected "Show only enabled breakpoint" button under breakpoint. Unselect the button to collapse the breakpoint.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: This is not the issue of the OP, they want the breakpoints to be closed and not **expanded** by default.